# Looking for jQuery find(..) method that  includes the current node

Tags: jquery

The jQuery [find(..)](http://api.jquery.com/find/) traversal method doesn't include the current node - it starts with the children of the current node.  What is the best way to call a find operation that includes the current node in its matching algorithm? Looking through the docs nothing immediately jumps out at me.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

For jQuery 1.8 and up, you can use [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/). It takes a selector so you don't need to filter the result:

```
object.find('selector').addBack('selector')
```

Prior to jQuery 1.8 you were stuck with [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/),  (now deprecated and removed) which then needed filtering:

```
object.find('selector').andSelf().filter('selector')
```

Comment: I've bundled this up as a plugin jquery.findIncludeSelf, registered with bower.  See https://github.com/ronen/jquery.findIncludeSelf

Comment: @ronen An extra file for something which can be done in one line? Thanks, but no thanks.

Comment: @prc322 an extra file doesn't bother me for deployments which bundle all the javascript into a single file anyway.  Generally I prefer using (tested) library methods even for simple things, rather than cluttering my code with stuff that I find harder to read and that introduces more possibilities for bugs.  In this case in particular, IMHO the need to specify `'selector'` twice makes the encapsulation extra desirable.  YMMV

Comment: Ok so I might be being thick but so you don't have to specify `'selector'` twice, ( as mentioned by @ronen ), couldn't you just use `object.parent().find('selector')`??? — that being said I like the idea of a lib that does it for you.

Comment: @circa1983 `object.parent().find('selector')` includes siblings of `object` and their descendants.

Answer (score 41):

You can't do this directly, the closest I can think of is using [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) and calling [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
$(selector).find(oSelector).andSelf().filter(oSelector)
//or...
$(selector).find('*').andSelf().filter(oSelector);
```

Unfortunately [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) doesn't take a selector, which would be handy.

Comment: You even added a comment to the jquery page right after answering this question http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/#comment-50124533 Now that's thoroughness. Nice! I did my due diligence and 'Liked' that one too.

Comment: The second one would be mindbogglingly slow. The first is simply just slow.

Comment: @Tgr - I don't disagree, though the first shouldn't be that show unless you're dealing with a *very* large number of elements.  If you don't need to chain you can skip re-filtering those elements for sure.

Comment: Interestingly, `closest(..)` includes the current DOM element and up the tree whereas all down-the-tree traversal methods like `find(..)` etc don't match the current element. It's as if the jQuery team purposefully implemented these for no overlap when both operations used together for a full vertical search.

Comment: @jdk - `.find()` is more analogous to `.parents()` in this case...if you look at what's available though, any parent operation can climb `.parentNode` (this is what happens inside jQuery), so it's a much easier than finding descendants...since there's not a lot there for a child tree, you have to compare a whole tree instead of a linear path.

Comment: Keep in mind that .andSelf() has been deprecated as of v1.8 and replaced with .addBack() that takes a selector as an argument. See http://api.jquery.com/addBack/

Comment: 1) Won't work if current node is part of selector. $('#myuniqueid').find('#myuniqueid *').andSelf().filter('#myuniqueid *'). 2) Will seem to work but it's actually not.

Answer (score 10):

Define

```
$.fn.findSelf = function(selector) {
    var result = this.find(selector);
    this.each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(selector)) {
            result.add($(this));
        }
    });
    return result;
};
```

then use

```
$.findSelf(selector);
```

instead of

```
$find(selector);
```

Sadly jQuery does not have this built-in. Really strange for so many years of development. My AJAX handlers weren't applied to some top elements due to how .find() works.

Comment: This is buggy. It adds all of "self", even if only one of them matches... -- One reason for this bug is a crappily named jQuery method...

Comment: I tried to fix the bug you have reported. Does it work properly now?

Comment: Most other answers use `filter()` there, which makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('selector').find('otherSelector').add($('selector').filter('otherSelector'))
```

You can store `$('selector')` in a variable for speedup. You can even write a custom function for this if you need it a lot:

```
$.fn.andFind = function(expr) {
  return this.find(expr).add(this.filter(expr));
};

$('selector').andFind('otherSelector')
```

Comment: This only works if you're *starting* with a selector though, which may not be the case.  Also, it's incorrect, it would be `$('selector').find('otherSelector').add($('otherSelector'))`, what you have now is equivalent to `.andSelf()`.  Lastly, the `.andFind()` doesn't filter based on the expression, you would need to `.add($(this).filter(expr))` :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: yeah, I forgot the filtering part, fixed now. It doesn't really matter if `$('selector')` is replaced by some other method of getting a jQuery object (if that is what you meant by not starting with a selector), `add()` can handle anything just as `$()` can.

Comment: My point was that your `$('selector')` may be `$('selector').children('filter').closest('.class').last()`...it may be in a chain and you have no idea what that object you're adding is, so the generic solution should take the previous object like the filter does :)

Comment: I still don't see why that would be a problem. `this` is whatever jQuery object a plugin was called on. It could be just as well be the result of a call chain.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is very inefficient and filters the set of elements that are already matched.

```
//find descendants that match the selector
var $selection = $context.find(selector);
//filter the parent/context based on the selector and add it
$selection = $selection.add($context.filter(selector);
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but there's a more correct way. If order is important, for example when you're matching a selector like `:first`, I wrote up a little function that will return the exact same result as if `find()` actually included the current set of elements:

```
$.fn.findAll = function(selector) {
  var $result = $();

  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    $result = $result.add(this.eq(i).filter(selector));
    $result = $result.add(this.eq(i).find(selector));
  }

  return $result.filter(selector);
};
```

It's not going to be efficient by any means, but it's the best I've come up with to maintain proper order.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the chaining to work properly use the snippet below.

```js
$.fn.findBack = function(expr) {
    var r = this.find(expr);
    if (this.is(expr)) r = r.add(this);
    return this.pushStack(r);
};
```

After the call of the end function it returns the #foo element.

```js
$('#foo')
    .findBack('.red')
        .css('color', 'red')
    .end()
    .removeAttr('id');
```

Without defining extra plugins, you are stuck with this.

```js
$('#foo')
    .find('.red')
        .addBack('.red')
            .css('color', 'red')
        .end()
    .end()
    .removeAttr('id');
```

Comment: Ah, no... If `this` is more than one element `this.is()` is already satisfied if only one of them matches.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are looking for **exactly one element**, either current element or one inside it, you can use:

```
result = elem.is(selector) ? elem : elem.find(selector);
```

In case you are looking for **multiple elements** you can use:

```
result = elem.filter(selector).add(elem.find(selector));
```

The use of `andSelf`/`andBack` is pretty rare, not sure why. Perhaps because of the performance issues some guys mentioned before me.

(I now noticed that **Tgr** already gave that second solution)

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to find a **solution which does not repeat itself** (i.e. not entering the same selector twice).

And this tiny jQuery extention does it:

```
jQuery.fn.findWithSelf = function(...args) {
  return this.pushStack(this.find(...args).add(this.filter(...args)));
};
```

It combines `find()` (only descendants) with `filter()` (only current set) and supports whatever arguments both eat. The `pushStack()` allows for `.end()` to work as expected.

Use like this:

```
$(element).findWithSelf('.target')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) is what you want:

```
obj.find(selector).andSelf()
```

Note that this will always add back the current node, whether or not it matches the selector.

Answer (score 1):

If you are strictly looking in the current node(s) the you just simply do

```
$(html).filter('selector')
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's the right (but sad) truth:

```
$(selector).parent().find(oSelector).filter($(selector).find('*'))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SergeJcqmn/MeQb8/2/

Comment: doesn't work with detached nodes (and the document itself), however.

Comment: Uh, no, this will remove `$(selector)` itself from the set in all cases.