# Can I use .find() and .filter() at the same time?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery object that contains the following HTML. It looks like this.

```
var myObject = $('<div><a href="#">Link A</a></div><a href="#">Link B</a>.');
```

I want to modify all `<a>` tags in it using .each() like so:

```
myObject.find('a').each(function () {
    $(this).text( "Modified Link Text" );
});
```

I would like the end result to be that Link A and Link B have their text modified. Unfortunately, if I understand this correctly, .find() will only look at the descendants of the top level element. Link A is nested in a `<div>` tag so it works. But Link B is not and is skipped.

Is there anyway I can target both Link A and Link B without repeating my code using .find() AND .filter()?

Here is a codepen I made: http://codepen.io/jimmykup/pen/DKgJn?editors=101

Comment: Have you looked at `.addBack()`? (http://api.jquery.com/addback/)

Comment: At the same time, no, however you can use them one after the other and /or together.

Comment: Also, this may be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828019/looking-for-jquery-find-method-that-includes-the-current-node

Comment: @CaseyFalk .addBack('a') worked right away. Thank you. Others are suggesting wrapping it in a tag and then using .find(). I'm wondering if one is more efficient than the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here 3 suggestions. You can

A) create a DOM node an find your element inside it :

```
var myObject = $('<div><a href="#">Link A</a></div><a href="#">Link B</a>.');

$('<div>').append(myObject).find('a').each(function () {
    $(this).text( "Modified Link Text" );
});
```

B) Use `addBack()` with a selector:

```
myObject.find('a').addBack('a').each(function () {
    $(this).text( "Modified Link Text" );
});
```

C) Directly add the filtered element with `.add()`

```
myObject.find('a').add(myObject.filter('a')).each(function () {
    $(this).text( "Modified Link Text" );
});
```

*Note : the loop is useless if you only change the text.*

Comment: I was able to get option B to work without using .filter('a'). I just put the selector in .addBack('a'). On another note, why do you say that the loop is useless if I'm only changing text? My end goal is actually about changing attributes in all anchor tags. But I'm curious why you say that.

Comment: @jimmykup - Most jQuery methods, like `text`, will iterate on their own, so you don't really need an extra loop, it's just overhead, unless of course you're doing other things in the loop

Comment: ^Exactly. And thank for the tip on `addBack`, didn't know it accept a parameter.

Comment: @jimmykup: Regarding your efficiency comment, here's a JSPerf with Karl's options: http://jsperf.com/adding-a-previous-element-to-a-jquery-set (feel free to use/edit it @Karl). Gist: addBack was fastest for me (slightly).

Comment: @CaseyFalk Thank for that jsPerf! As for me, the `add()` method is the fastest, but the difference is minor. It's like half a thousand operations difference. You won't even notice it.

Comment: That makes sense; I would assume that `addBack` calls `add` at some point anyway, haha. Probably just a hiccup in my browser or something...

Comment: Thanks everyone. I decided on addBack because its just easier to write. Not having to wrap and unwrap is ideal.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do this is to wrap it in an extra element, then just use `find`, as it excludes the parent element anyway

```
$('<div />').append(myObject).find('a').text( "Modified Link Text" );
```

Comment: I'll be outputting the resulting HTML later. At which point I would want/need to take it back out of that wrapper. Would you say it's more efficient to do it this way, or to skip the wrapper altogether and use .addBack() that people are suggesting.

Comment: @jimmykup `$('.selector').append(myObject);` will get it out of the wrapper.

Comment: ^ Indeed, you already have a reference to the elements without the wrapper, but I guess it depends on what you're doing really, I use both methods all the time

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addBack` with a filter like this:

```
myObject.find('a').addBack('a').each(...)
```

Here is a `findAndSelf` extension to jQuery I use to do this (as I use this pattern a lot):

```
jQuery.fn.findAndSelf = function(selector){
   return this.find(selector).addBack(selector);
};
```

Your code would then look like:

```
myObject.findAndSelf('a').each(function () {
    $(this).text("Modified Link Text");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Put all string in a single parent div like this :

```
var myObject = $('<div><div><a href="#">Link A</a></div><a href="#">Link B</a>.</div>');
```

Comment: "Can I use .find() and .filter() at the same time?" -- This doesn't answer OP's question, bud. : )