# Jquery load() doesn't load script tags in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-load

**Page 1** has a Menu with id (#navigation), with a link called Page2 and DIV with id (global_content) that shows contents when the link Page2 is clicked. In the same page (Page 1) I wrote a jquery load function, so that when I click the link it should display the content without page reload. The load event works fine, the content is shown, but without the script tags that the **Page 2** has.

**This is the code in Page 1**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //jQuery('#navigation li a').click(function(){
    jQuery('#navigation li').on('click', 'a', function(){

    var toLoad = jQuery(this).attr('href')+' #global_content';
    jQuery('#global_content').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);
    jQuery('#load').remove();
    jQuery('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    jQuery('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    function loadContent() {
        jQuery('#global_content').load(toLoad, function() {
        jQuery('#global_content').fadeIn('fast', hideLoader());

        });
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        jQuery('#global_content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        jQuery('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

    });
}); </script>
```

**This is the code in Page 2**

```
<div id="wall-feed-scripts">

  <script type="text/javascript">

    Wall.runonce.add(function () {

      var feed = new Wall.Feed({
        feed_uid: 'wall_91007',
        enableComposer: 1,
        url_wall: '/widget/index/name/wall.feed',
        last_id: 38,
        subject_guid: '',
        fbpage_id: 0      });

      feed.params = {"mode":"recent","list_id":0,"type":""};

      feed.watcher = new Wall.UpdateHandler({
        baseUrl: en4.core.baseUrl,
        basePath: en4.core.basePath,
        identity: 4,
        delay: 30000,
        last_id: 38,
        subject_guid: '',
        feed_uid: 'wall_91007'
      });
      try {
        setTimeout(function () {
          feed.watcher.start();
        }, 1250);
      } catch (e) {
      }

    });

  </script>
</div>

<div class="wallFeed">
some content
</div>
```

**But the output i get is**

```
<div id="wall-feed-scripts"></div>

 <div class="wallFeed">
    some content
    </div>
```

Can you help please?

Comment: This is by design, `<scripts>` are not loaded/executed.

Comment: You will want to use [`$.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: @JayBlanchard, but getScripts() means i have to put the js script inside a file .js

Comment: So? What is the issue with that? You should separate your code as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bypass the restrictions of [`jQuery.load` stripping `<script>` tags](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/load.js#L54) by using [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) directly, which is the underlying method used for the [shorthand methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) `load`, `get`, `post` etc..
We'll use [jquery.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/), which uses `innerHTML`, to update the DOM.

```
var toLoad         = this.href,
    toLoadSelector = '#global_content';

...

function loadContent() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: toLoad,
        success: function(data,status,jqXHR) {
            data = jQuery(data).find( toLoadSelector );
            jQuery('#global_content').html(data).fadeIn('fast', hideLoader());
        }
    });
}
```

As you see, we apply the selector `toLoadSelector` (`'#global_content'`) on the reponse to only insert the desired portion of the page.

**UPDATE**

A better approach is to introduce some parameters to the `loadContent` function so it is more easily reusable. Here's an updated (and tested) version:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

    $('#navigation li a').on('click', function() {
        loadContent( '#global_content', this.href, '#global_content' );
        return false;
    });

    function loadContent(target, url, selector) {

        $(target).fadeOut('fast', function() {

            showLoader();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function(data,status,jqXHR) {
                    $(target).html($(data).find(selector).addBack(selector).children())
                    .fadeIn('fast', hideLoader());
                }
            });

        });
    }

    function showLoader() {
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>').fadeIn('normal');
    }

    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
});
</script>
```

---

A few notes on the changes:

```
jQuery(function() { ... })
```

is the same as

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() { ... } )
```

Specifying `function($)` makes `jQuery` available as `$` within the function, which saves some typing.

Now, regarding this expression:

```
$(data).find(selector).addBack(selector).children()
```

Unfortunately, `$("<div id='foo'>").find('#foo')` does not return any results: only descendants are matched. This means that if **Page2** has the `#global_content` div directly under `<body>`, it will not work. Adding [`addBack(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/) makes it possible to match the top-level element itself. See [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828019/looking-for-jquery-find-method-that-includes-the-current-node) for more details.

The `.children()` makes sure that the `<div id='global_content'>` tag from **Page2** is not itself included, otherwise **Page1** will have

```
<div id="global_content">
    <div id="global_content">
```

which is technically illegal, since an `id` must be unique in a document.

Comment: This code loads the header aswell. Is it possible to load only the #global_content contents?

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @Jay Where do you see *"try this"*?

Comment: @Alvin what do you mean, loads the header? This should replace the contents (`innerHTML`) of `#global_content` with whatever the `toLoad` url returns.

Comment: Is the brackets needed here `hideLoader()`? `fadeIn` takes the second parameter a function.

Comment: Kenney, so how can I load only the part of the page? Because this code loads the whole page into my div

Comment: You haven't provided *any* explanation, so this is the equivalent of a "try this" answer.

Comment: @Kenney, well, previously my code used to return the specific part of the Page 2 with .load and FadeIn. But now, the code actually loads this content but with the menu and the links. Page 1 and Page 2 has the same menu bar.

Comment: @Kenney it returns the page content but with header and footer insite my div #global_content

Comment: @AlvinOfori-Adjei Your `toLoad` appends ` #global_content` in order to load that part of the page, however, I don't see `id="global_content"` in your Page2. Can I assume that there is a `<div id='global_content'>` around your Page2 that you didn't post?

Comment: @Kenney exactly! My bad! Yes, there is id="global_content" in Page 2. Page 2 also has a header and footer the same as Page 1. So all I need is to get only what is inside the id="global_content"

Comment: @Kenney so how can I achieve that?

Comment: @Alvin Thanks for the clarification. Updated the answer!

Comment: You're welcome! Btw, added a link to the source of `.load` - it uses `jQuery.parseHTML` if you specify a selector after the URL, and this is what strips the `<script>` tags.

Comment: @Kenney can you help me please? How can I do a multiple select? Like `toLoadSelector = '#global_content';` then `toLoadSelector = '#something else';` and after that load all in `jQuery('#global_content').html(data).fadeIn('fast', hideLoader());`

Comment: @Alvin I updated the answer. I think this format will help you do that more easily: simply call `loadContent( '#global_content', 'some-url', '#something-else' );`.

Comment: @Kenney, thank you so much, it works!! I am writing another question about a music play when a message is received

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue. As noted in the comments, jQuery ignores script tags when loading content via `load()`. Someone mentioned you should use `$.getScript()` but that won't work in strict mode because stuff loaded via `getScript()` is loaded via `eval()` and can't access the global scope. So `getScript()` will break your javascript. The only way around it is to use vanilla javascript.

```
// $.getScript() uses eval() which makes it impossible to define functions in 
// the global namespace in strict mode. Hence the closure thing here...
(function (callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", "./app/js/sequences/autoloader.php");
    script.addEventListener('load', callback);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
})(function () {
    // Callback funtion here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but it is not very clear to me how i should implement this code with my own code. Can you help me please?