# jQuery find() including current node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to select elements with jQuery's `find()` method. This method searches the children of a node but it does not include the node itself which I want to be considered aswell. In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828019/looking-for-jquery-find-method-that-includes-the-current-node) they proposed to do it like this:

```
object.find('selector').addBack('selector')
```

It seemed to be a good workaround for me, but unfortunately this solution does not work with every selector. Assume I have some nodes

```
<div class="someClass">
  <div></div>
  <div class="someClass">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and want to use the childselector `'.someClass > *'` (or a similar one that affects the current node and its descendants). I expect to get the 2 `div` elements and the `span`, but I obvously only get the span element.

Does someone know a workaround or another method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for jQuery find(..) method that  includes the current node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828019/looking-for-jquery-find-method-that-includes-the-current-node)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't worried about picking up sibling elements, you could begin your query from the parent of the node you started with. That will ensure that the node in question is included in the query.

```js
const selector = '.someClass > *';
let $node = $('body > .someClass');
let $matches = $node.parent().find(selector);
console.log($matches)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someClass">
  <div></div>
  <div class="someClass">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does not work either when using a child-selector (>) if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Felix You're right, I missed that part of the question. Updated my answer to use a different approach.