# In a loop, find a span that is at the top level or a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5caho9e/)

Within a looping function I will get html strings that have a `span` element either at the top level or also it could be as a child within a `div`. How can I find it in either case?

I know `find` only searches children. Not even sure how to find it when it is in the top level, as in `data2` below? If I did, then I guess I'd do a `find` first, and if it's length was 0, then do the search for the `span` in the top level.

```
var data1 = "<div class='form-group'><span class='editableColumn'>NAT</span><input type='text' class='editableColumn form-control' style='display:none' name='Lot' value='NAT'></div>";

var data2 = "<span class='editableColumn'>Yes</span><input type='checkbox' name='IsBackorder' class='editableColumn editor-active' style='display:none' checked='checked' value='true'>";
var myStringArray = [data1, data2];
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;


$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log(myStringArray[i]);
    //Do something
    var span = $(data1).find("span.editableColumn").text();
    $("#" + i).text(span);
  }

})
```

Comment: Have you tried `.closest()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for jQuery find(..) method that  includes the current node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828019/looking-for-jquery-find-method-that-includes-the-current-node)

Comment: @johnny_the_programmer it seems the `addBack()` does a double lookup, so it is replicating the result. See updated fiddle using `addBack()` here: http://jsfiddle.net/g4p19n2e/ You'll see 'NAT' is replicated as 'NATNAT'.

Comment: @Souleste `.closest()' does not work. See fiddle test here: http://jsfiddle.net/g4p19n2e/2/

Comment: @ChadRichardson http://jsfiddle.net/a21sk6dx/ It seems to work for me!

Comment: @johnny_the_programmer ah...yes indeed. I wasn't adding the selector in the `addBack()` method. Thanks for the clarification. I do like this solution better as it is less lines of code. If you want to make it an answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .addBack() to do it in one line if you prefer that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var span = $(myStringArray[i]).find("span.editableColumn").addBack("span.editableColumn").text();
    $("#" + i).text(span);
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a21sk6dx/

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML had parents, you could do: `$(myStringArray[i]).parent().closest("span.editableColumn").text();`

Since you don't, you either need to wrap your data2 in a , or try find then closest:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log();
    //Do something
    var span = $(myStringArray[i]).find("span.editableColumn").text();
    if (!span) span = $(myStringArray[i]).closest("span.editableColumn").text();
    $("#" + (i + 1)).text(span);
  }
})
```

Also, watch out: You've got i=0, < arrayLength, so it would only run through 0 and 1, and you have your ID's as 1 & 2, hence the `$("#" + (i + 1))`

Comment: Perfect. For reference, here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4p19n2e/1/